# Flutter ipad apps

Tags: flutter, ipad, flutter-ios, flutter-ios-build

Do Flutter apps that work well on Ios phones automatically work well on iPads? I don't care about the styles & layout (that is taken care of), but more in terms of OS specifics.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, flutter supports iPadOS and is going to continue that for the future [[1]](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/34719).
This means that all OS specifics, such as integration with `HealthKit` will also be available for iPad apps.
And via the automatically generated Xcode project you have more granular control over which operating systems your app will support.

But as you are already aware, a layout that works well on iOS might not work well on iPad.